# What do you call an instance of a struct?

Tags: c, class, struct

This is purely out of interest. I searched around a bit, knowing that instances of `classes` are called `objects`, but I couldn't find what the correct word is for an instance of a `struct` in C, C++, C#, etc. Do we even have a word for this?

Comment: It is object for any language or construct.

Comment: Maybe Struct initialization ?

Comment: Structject would be a cool word though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is perfectly valid to call it an object even in C.

**C99 Standard §3.15:**
**Para 1:**

> object
>   region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent
>   values

Answer (score 4):

In C and C++ word 'object' is much more general. It refers also to structure objects or primitives. From C99 standard:

> **object**
>
> region of data storage in the execution environment, the
> contents of which can represent values

In C++ classes and structures are equivalent and types defined with `struct` are also considered class types. Standard uses expressions like `object of class type` or `object of class X`.